# Including multiple levels of objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Thats my database code:

```
public class Question {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Answer> Answers {get; set;}

    public Question() {
        Answers = new List<Answer>();
    }
}

public class Answer {
    public ind Id {get; set;}
    public string Message {get; set;}

    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("QuestionId")]
    public Question Question { get; set; }

    public int? PictureId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PictureId")]
    public Picture Picture { get; set; }

    public int KeywordId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("KeywordId")]
    public Keyword Keyword { get; set; }

    public int? VideoId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("VideoId")]
    public Video Videos { get; set; }
}

public class Picture {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Url {get; set;}
}

public class Keyword {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Text {get; set;}
}

public class Video {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Url {get; set;}
}
```

What I want to archive is to load all questions with answers with picture and keyword (I dont want to load `Video`. This code:

```
public static List<Question> GetQuestions() {
    using (var context = new DatabaseContext()) {
        return context.Questions
            .Include(x => x.Answers.Select(y => y.Keyword))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Is giving me all questions with all answers with keyword. I dont really know how to attach picture too. I think there is a better way to do it instead of selecting all objects one by one (still I am not sure it is possible). Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overload for `Include`, that allows you to use a string that represents any property you may need.

```
context.Questions.Include("Answers.Picture")
                 .Include("Answers.Keyword")
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try:

```
return context.Questions
.Include(x => x.Answers.Select(y => y.Keyword))
.Include(x => x.Answers.Select(y => y.Picture))
.ToList();
```

or use projection using a Select at the end (then all includes are ignored anyway):

```
return context.Questions
.Select(x => new Answers(){x.Keyword,x.Picture }
.ToList();
```